# Spring Security: WSSecurity (WSSE/SOAP) with SAML token using spring security (by looking-up user into LDAP)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

Need help on securing a SOAP WS with WSSE SAML TOKEN by using Spring security.

We are using `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor` to intercept the endpoint wsdl.

Exception:

> Intercept the wsdl having SAML token and validate the user against
>   LDAP

Details are as below:

endpoint: http://localhost:8080/swss-soap-example-1.3.0/password/plain/xwss/profileService

input payload:

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">         
            <saml:Assertion AssertionID="SAML-pYkHWi487VIpBoT821ysBQ22" IssueInstant="2015-08-18T18:41:28Z" 
                            Issuer="www.oracle.com" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
              <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2015-08-18T18:41:28Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
                 <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">admin</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                       <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:sender-vouches</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                 </saml:Subject>
              </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
            </saml:Assertion>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

---

### applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
      <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:security/endpoint/security-password-plain-endpoint.xml" />
      <property name="callbackHandlers">
         <list/>
        <!--list>
           <ref bean="validationHandler" />
        </list-->
      </property>
   </bean>
```

---

### securityPolicy.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
   <!--xwss:RequireUsernameToken
      passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false" /-->
   <xwss:RequireSAMLAssertion type="SV" keyReferenceType="Identifier" />
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Comment: Any examples would help us..

Comment: we were able to secure soap WS with WSSE UserNameToken and authenticate with LDAP integration. But not sure how can we acheive the same on WSSE SAML sendvocher token. Does @Spring Security supports it.